# Will Apple approve an App that asks the user to enter his credit card number?

Tags: iphone, credit-card, billing

From reading discussions I understood that Apple will not approve an App that asks the user to enter his credit card number.

Is that correct?

Is there any way around it?

Thanks-

Nir.

Comment: When you checked with representatives of Apple, what did they say?

Comment: I did not get an answer- 
their answer is that they can not provide me with any information regarding of what they will approve or not before they get the actual App to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've heard is not correct. Many apps, such as the Amazon app, allow the user to enter their credit card number.

Answer (score 0):

Apple rarely turns away apps for limited functionality, so one approach might be a simple-as-possible app which sends a credit card number to a secure server and see if it gets through.